# Undo to a specific user defined point

Tags: undo-redo

I'm using `U` in normal mode to undo steps in vim, I wonder how to set a sort of a bookmark and create a undo command to undo steps/reverse to the bookmark moment in Vim. This would be nicer than just keep pressing `U`.

Comment: What about using git? I think this is one of the purposes of version control. git provides also the feature called stash to keep your uncommitted changes when checking out a previous commit.

Comment: If git is too much for what you want, consider plugins which visualize the undo steps as a tree with timestamps, e.g. https://github.com/mbbill/undotree.

Comment: @Hotschke I'm trying to avoid git for this, sometimes I need to test a several lines and see the result and come back to the moment before test. for just steps under 10, I don't want to use git.

Comment: Depending on how far back in time you want to undo you can either use git (or any versionning system like SVN or whatever) or a undo plugin line [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) or [mundo](https://github.com/simnalamburt/vim-mundo) **EDIT** Oups I didn't see the second comment of @Hotschke

Comment: @undotree is looking cool!

Comment: My [histwin](https://github.com/chrisbra/histwin.vim) plugin allows to define marks in the undo history

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks man, that's what I'm looking for!

Comment: BTW: for undotree see this [wishlist](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree/issues/8) request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Via Plugins

- [mbbill/undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) (this is what I use)
- [simnalamburt/vim-mundo](https://github.com/simnalamburt/vim-mundo)
- [chrisbra/histwin](https://github.com/chrisbra/histwin.vim)

#### Via External Tooling

Consider using VCS systems like git or mercurial (the two leading distributed systems).

---

Aside: your question mentions capital `U`, which has very different effects from `u`. They both have their uses, but my goto is usually `u` because it truly "undoes."

Plus, `<Leader>u` makes a good mapping for, e.g., undotree’s command.